# How can I see if my boyfriend has added a listening, tracking app on my zte?/

Tags: security

I believe that my boyfriend has put a hidden app on my phone that enables him to read all my text messages, phone calls and know my location. How can I see if he has done this ?

Comment: First off, put a pin on your phone that he doesn't know. And don't leave it alone with him. And get a new boyfriend - obviously you don't trust this one.

Answer (score 0):

PC World had an [article](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3085112/android/keep-spies-off-your-android-phone.html) on the topic a little while back and recommended [Anti Spy Mobile Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.free) and [Anti Spy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skibapps.antispyforandroid).

Be careful when using them - judging by their descriptions, they appear to be using heuristics that might be fooled by legit apps in some cases. Of course, if they show an app that's deliberately hiding itself and can read your text messages, it's probably spyware.